# Azure App Service unload time with health check

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-appservice

Azure App Service instances can be unloaded after 20min of inactivity, but does anyone know how this is impacted by health checks? In particular, does enabling health check to prevent the application of being unloaded? If so, does that lead to increased costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Health Check will keep the application alive as they continuously ping the health check endpoint in a specific time.

However a better way to keep the application alive is by using the setting [AlwaysOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-general-settings) within Azure App Service settings.

Regarding the cost, the App Service are always billed even if they are inactive. Once provisioned, the meter will keep ticking and active/inactive web app will not have any impact on costs whatsoever.

Comment: If my understanding of this answer is correct, does that mean that unloading the app after 20min serves no purpose?

Comment: yeah, unloading the app after 20 minutes will not save any costs. Generally most Azure services continue to charge if provisioned. However, in case of VM, if it is stopped, there are no charges. So if cost consideration is important you may host app on VM instead of App service for non-prod. However it is not recommended for prod apps and like going backward.